# Android HTTPUrlConnection Get Request Full Data

Tags: android, http, get

I was wondering how to get all the data when I do a http get call? I've added setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Chrome/30.0.0.0") and more data but I'm still missing like 1/4 of the data that I wanted.

```
    URL site;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    String result = "";

    try {
        site = new URL(uri);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) site.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Chrome/30.0.0.0");
        conn.connect();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String s = "";
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += s;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // Finally disconnect
        conn.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: How do you know you are missing the data? did you try to write it into a file?

Comment: I just typed the same url into the browser and saw the completed data set I wanted. Is it not possible?

Comment: it's possible, but why did you come to a conclusion that you can't get all the data?

Comment: But that's why I'm asking the question, I don't understand how to get the rest of the data and I google around and try different steps, but it's just trial and error to get more data. It's json, but I've only gotten 3 out of the 17. I believe it's giving me in chunks.